# How to create (on Windows) a file with a extension different that mime type ?

Tags: windows, command

I have a problem. 
In my PHP code, I want to check if the file uploaded have its extension similar of its mime type :

```
for image.png: 
 if this extension (.png) is associated to the png mime type( image/png ) 
   upload is authorised. 

 if this extension (.png) is not associated to the png mime type, (ex : text/html)
   upload is not authorised.
```

I know we can change the type mime of the file on HTTP Request (on the file's header) . But, for my tests I need to create a file with a mime type different from its extension.

Do you know I want create this file? ("image.png" with "application/octet-stream" mime type).

On windows, when I change the file's extension, this change also the mime type...

I found a page for create a file with "Appcmd.exe" on Windows, but this software don't exist on my computer...

Comment: Windows doesn't store any meta information with files. The file type is identified purely by its extension. If you need to create a file in Windows' file system, the mime type you pass is ignored, as far as the file system is concerned.

Comment: Okay, Thanks you very much! Do you know if it's possible with another OS? Mac or Linux?